# When I make migrations I get this error, what could be the reason?

Tags: python-3.x, django, model, migration, traceback

[**I cloned the repository. Then I added several fields to the model and wanted to add them to an existing database. I ran the makemigrations command and got this error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a68zK.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't share code/errors as images. Especially not linked ones. We need the code in order to help you.

Comment: Without any code or informations... complicated. Error maybe means you have previous migrations that do not make sense with actual state of model

Answer (score 0):

1. ===> Remove all migration from maigrations folder
2. ===> python manage.py makemigrations yourappname
3. ===> python manage.py migrate

Comment: Before step 1, you need to rollback all migrations (or any of them) with ./manage.py migrate appname previous_migration_name. Simply deleting the migration files may cause errors for future migrations, as your database will not change its state.